# Finding the sum of the series with $a_n = \frac{4n}{6n+7}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> In my calc 2 course, one of the homework problems is to let
> $$a_n = \frac{4n}{6n+7}$$
> and then find the limit of its sequence and the sum of its series.

I started with the limit:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{4n}{6n+7}$$
Using L'Hopital, I ended up with $\dfrac{2}{3}$ as the answer.

The sum of the series is where I seem to be having trouble.

So with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4n}{6n+7}$, I generated the first 3 terms of the series:

$$\frac{4}{13} + \frac{8}{19} + \frac{12}{25} + \cdots $$

To me this series does not appear to be geometric, so I tried to utilize a definition I was provided with in class:

> A series converges iff the sequence, $S_n$ converges. If $S_n$ converges, we say that $\lim_{n\to \infty} S_n = S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4n}{6n+7}$, where $S$ is some real finite number.

Based on this, the sum of the series would have to also be $\frac{2}{3}$ but when I entered this as my answer, it was marked as incorrect.

So at this point, I'm thinking I might have gotten this definition incorrect or there is some way to algebraically manipulate $a_n$ to get a geometric "form" that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Since the limit of $a_n$ is not $0$, its series diverges.

Comment: You are in the case where $S_n$ does not converge.

Comment: I just checked my notes, and I don't seem to have anything about that written down. Would one of you mind posting an answer with further explanation?

Comment: "*A series converges iff the sequence, $S_n$ converges*"  You must have grossly misheard what they were talking about.  A series converges iff the sequence **of partial sums** $S_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k$ converges.  This is a totally different statement than saying the sequence of **summands** $a_n$ converges.  Consider $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 1 = 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+\dots$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh boy...we had defined $S_n$ as the sequence of partial sums. I completely forgot about that as I was working. Thanks.

Comment: @UnderMathUate - In the words of my advanced calculus teacher, using L'Hopital to compute the limit of $a_n$ is "using a cannon to kill a flea." It was a good-natured response when I suggested computing a similar limit to yours via L'Hopital (and that's how I intend it here). Whenever you need the limit at infinity of a quotient of non-constant polynomials of the same degree, divide numerator and denominator by the high power of the variable. You'll be left with the ratio of the leading terms after taking the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously confused the limit of the sequence $a_n $ with that of its partial sums:
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k,
$$
which diverges in this case because $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\frac23\ne0$.

Comment: Yep, I just realized that's exactly what happened.

Answer (score 1):

There are already several complete answers here. I would like to suggest a strategy.

Spend a little time just thinking about the shape of the problem before you start applying tools.

When $n$ is large, the fraction
$$
\frac{4n}{6n+7}
$$
is very close to
$$
\frac{4n}{6n } = \frac{2}{3}
$$
(since the $+7$ in the denominator is negligible)
so that will be the limit of the sequence. You don't need anything like L'Hopital's rule to prove that. I would accept a student's statement that it was "obvious" if the surrounding work was good. If you do want a more formal proof, write
$$
\frac{4n}{6n+7} =
\frac{4}{6+7/n}
$$
and look at the limit of the numerator over the limit of the denominator.

Once you know the terms are near $2/3$ when $n$ is large you know the sequence ehds up looking like
$$
\cdots + 2/3 + 2/3 + \cdots
$$
which clearly diverges. The general term does not have limit $0$.

Comment: Thanks for this! Simplifying the steps really makes the answer a lot more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be unfamiliar with the term test for series divergence I am writing a more detailed answer. Let $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers. We define the sequence of partial sums for $(a_n)$ as follows:
$$s_n = a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n, \;\; n\geq 1$$
We say that the series with general term $a_n$ (or $\sum a_n$) converges if the sequence $(s_n)$ converges to a real number $l$. A necessary condition for a series to converge is that $a_n \to 0$. We can see this by noting that
$$a_n = s_n - s_{n-1}, \;\; n \geq 2$$
Assuming that $s_n \to l$ we can take limits on both sides of the above equality and conclude that $a_n \to l - l = 0$ since $(s_{n-1})$ converges to $l$ as well.

In your case, you have shown that $a_n \not\to 0$ so by contraposition the series with general term $a_n$ cannot converge.